# Javascript check/uncheck all button for treeview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, treeview

I want to have a linkbutton that when pressed checks/unchecks all the checkboxes on a treeview. How can I achieve this with Javascript?

I researched and found this code but I can't seem to make it work.

```
function selectAllNone(value) {
        var tvNodes = document.getElementById("Treeview1");
        var chBoxes = tvNodes.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < chBoxes.length; i++) {
            var chk = chBoxes[i];
            if (chk.type == "checkbox") {
                chk.checked = value;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Can you share the HTML?

Comment: Value comes out as undefined.

`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel10" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TreeView Id="Treeview1" ShowCheckBoxes="All"
                    ExpandDepth="0" runat="server">
                    </asp:TreeView>
 </ContentTemplate>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your function with some HTML and it does work (I modified the button function to toggle all check-boxes)

[See JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/angrybird/u8n8t7hh/21/)

```
function selectAllNone() {
var tvNodes = document.getElementById("trvMenu");   
var chBoxes = tvNodes.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < chBoxes.length; i++) {
    var chk = chBoxes[i];
    if (chk.type == "checkbox") {
        if(chk.checked == true)
        {
            chk.checked = false;
        }
        else if(chk.checked == false)
        {
            chk.checked = true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}

<form method="POST">
<div id="trvMenu">    
    <input type="checkbox">check box 1</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox">check box 2</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox">check box 3</input><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="selectAllNone()">Toggle Check Boxes</input><br>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Great, it worked @angrybirdnut , just had to change getElementById to getElementById("<%=Treeview1.ClientID %>");

But if you could help me again, I want it to select them all even if there is one checkbox checked and only toggle them all off if all of them are checked. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @MikeFerrer I added a function for the checkboxes feature. Check out this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/angrybird/u8n8t7hh/25/

Comment: Thanks for your help @angrybirdnut but I guess I didn't explain myself right. What I wanted was if a person selected one or two checkbox and then clicked on the select all button, it would select all the checkboxes. If all were selected and the person clicked on the button it would unselect them all. Hope I could make myself clear. Thanks for you help again.

Comment: @MikeFerrer If i understand it correctly this time...1) If none of the check-boxes are selected then clicking on the 'select all button' results in nothing. 2) If at least one check-box is selected, then clicking 'select all' selects all check-boxes. 3) If all check boxes are selected, then clicking the 'select-all' clears all the check boxes. This is what I have implemented in the attached code : http://jsfiddle.net/angrybird/u8n8t7hh/29/

Comment: 2) and 3) are correct, working great. But in 1) it should result in all selected. Could you help me with that? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: ok, makes it easier in that case . The code can be made cleaner/more concise but i just modified it to meet condition (1) : http://jsfiddle.net/angrybird/u8n8t7hh/30/